# Table is goin outta div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div with table

Here is code

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;margin-top: 85px; white-space: nowrap;">
<div style="float: left;width: 80%; table-layout: fixed;">
    <table class="table" style="width: 80%;border-style: solid;border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;border-collapse: separate">
        <tr>
            <th style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;">
                <b>Hours</b><b style="padding-left: 30px;"> Monday</b>
            </th>
            <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <b>Hours</b><b style="padding-left: 30px;"> Tuesday</b>
            </th>
            <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <b>Hours</b><b style="padding-left: 30px;"> Wednesday</b>
            </th>
            <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <b>Hours</b><b style="padding-left: 30px;">  Thursday</b>
            </th>
            <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <b>Hours</b><b style="padding-left: 30px;">  Friday</b>
            </th>
            <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <b>Hours</b><b style="padding-left: 30px;"> Saturday</b>
            </th>
            <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                <b>Hours</b><b style="padding-left: 30px;"> Sunday</b>
            </th>
         </tr>
        <tr>

          </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

My problem is table getting outta div

[image: Screen]

I try to use `table-layout: fixed;` but it seems not works.

Where is my mistake?

Thank's for help.

Comment: This looks like simple overflow. You can remove `width: 80%;` from `div` and `table` or remove `white-space: nowrap;`. The issues is that you content is more than width. How do you want this to handle? Please specify desired behaviour in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of your table cells is pushing the width of the table, which is why it cannot obey the width you set. You can easily see this by playing with the th font size in this example:

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-top: 85px;
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}

table {
  border: 3px solid #1d69b4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  display: block;
}

th {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.pad-left {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Hours Monday</th>
         <th>Hours Tuesday</th>
         <th>Hours Wednesday</th>
         <th>Hours Thursday</th>
         <th>Hours Friday</th>
         <th>Hours Saturday</th>
         <th>Hours Sunday</th>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Solution: adjust your content or your styling so it will fit your table.